# Correct word usage

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between 'Have you ever experienced an immediate dislike to someone?' versus 'Have you ever taken an immediate dislike to someone?'?

Thank you.

Comment: 'take a dislike to someone' but 'experience/have a dislike of / for'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Have you ever experienced an immediate dislike to someone?' is certainly less direct than 'Have you ever taken an immediate dislike to someone?'. The meaning is exactly the same, but the delivery is more "gentle" in the first sentence than the second.

Expanding on the "gentler" tone, the first sentence is more open-ended thant he second. The former focuses on the *"experience"* of immediately disliking a person, whereas the latter can imply that you have *"someone"* in mind while making the question.

Comment: As a native speaker, I find the first unidiomatic; it should be "experienced an immediate dislike for"